# Should I normalize (preprocess/scale/log-transform) my data "before" imputing missing values with missRanger?

Tags: r, regression, missing-data, normalization, data-imputation

I am trying to impute missing values using missRanger package. missRanger is apparently much faster than missForest.
I would like to know:
1 - Are these two packages any different in their imputation method?
2 - Since I want to log-transform my variables, should I do it "before" or "after" imputation of missing values?